# Azure OpenId Token validation

Tags: validation, azure, openid

I am new to azure, tokens and so on...
I have "digged" microsoft documentation and google and stackoverflow, but still didn't get full understanding.

So I using openId with Owin library to connect to azure from web app(VS2013 .net 4.5.1). And I have next code to do it:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {  
      app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(
       CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());  
      app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
       new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
                    AuthenticationType = policy,
                  
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
                        ,SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated
                        ,AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
                        ,SecurityTokenReceived = OnSecurityTokenReceived
                    },
                    Scope = "openid profile",
                    ResponseType = "id_token"               
                };
        );
    } 

private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
            var claims = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Claims;

            ClaimsPrincipal.Current.AddIdentity(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

And it is working, but in microsoft documentation I found next instruction "Currently, ID tokens are signed but not encrypted. When your app receives an ID token, it must validate the signature to prove the token's authenticity and validate a few claims in the token to prove its validity. The claims validated by an app vary depending on scenario requirements, but your app must perform some common claim validations in every scenario."

But there is SecurityTokenValidated-callback , which have AuthenticationTicket. So do I still need to somehow validate token/ticked or now it is handled automatically (I been tough in army that nothing happening automatically, but still)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library that you are using handles the validation for you.

It will check the signature is what it should be based on the keys provided by Azure AD.

So you don't need to do manual checks, other than your app's specific checks. For example, an app might allow only members of a certain group to access the app. You would need to do that check if that is the case.